# how to write a script that gets 2 files at the commandline reads from the other and writes into the other

Tags: linux, bash

write a bash file that takes two files at the command line and the first file you read from it and write to the next on for example ./file.sh input_file.txt output_file.txt

```
    #!/bin/bash

     read file1 file2

     exec 400<> file1.txt
     while read line1 <&400           #use towns.txt file discripter to inte$
         do
         {
            full_line=$line1
            echo $full_line >>file2.txt           
         }
         done
     exec 400>&-
```

Comment: What is your question Flint?  This does not seem to have a question, and appears to be an answer, and is likely to be closed as unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [positional parameters](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/bash-shell-positional-parameters/). In this instance you would use:

```
file1="$1" #input file
file2="$2" #output file
```

Then reference `file1` and `file2` throughout your script. When you run your script `file1` is the first parameter and `file2` is the second, like so:

`./myscript.sh input.txt output.txt`

Comment: But i have encountered a problem, file1 cannot write to file2                                                                      `                                                                    exec 400<> file1.txt
        while read line1 <&400          
         do
         {
            full_line=$line1
            echo $full_line >>file2.txt           
         }
         done
         exec 400>&-`